# How can I randomly generate one of two values for a string?

Tags: c#

I have a variable named a that I am currently giving the value:

```
var a = "test";
```

How can I make it so that the variable gets the value of "test" or "production" at random each time it is set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = (new Random()).Next(2) == 0? "test" : "production";
```

If you're running this repeatedly, you'll want to store the Random instance and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to use your method. I will mark as accepted in 9 minutes. I have another question about date. Hope you can help with that also.

Answer (score 11):

You'd need to use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random.aspx) class:

```
var r = new Random();
var a = r.Next(2) == 1 ? "test" : "production";
```

Here's another trick that's useful if you have more than one string you want to select randomly:

```
var r = new Random;
var strings = new[] { "test", "production" };
var a = strings[r.Next(strings.Length)];
```

Comment: Oooo forgot about NextBoolean. Nice. +1

Comment: @RyanBennett that's actually from Java, sorry. .NET only has Next, NextDouble, NextBytes, and Sample

Comment: Darn it. I thought `NextBoolean` might have been a tiny tweak added in 4.5 :(

Answer (score 2):

```
public string GetRandomString()
{
   Random rand = new Random();
   var random = rand.Next(0,1);
   return random == 0 ? "test" : "production";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Random` class:

```
Random r = new Random();
string a;
if (r.NextDouble() > 0.5) a = "test";
else a = "production";
```